# Is it dangerous to share my user agent publicly?

Tags: scrapy, user-agent, privacy

I'm doing a scrapy project for fun and wanted to upload the code to Github. My user-agent is in the code and I was wondering if It's safe to share this information publicly.

Comment: it is very easy to spoof public user agent

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you recommending I should not share it on GitHub because of how easy it is to spoof it?  @M.Twarog

Comment: Just look at your agent string. It's very likely that it's completely vanilla and indistinguishable from a million others, so unless it contains something odd like a unique-looking hash, don't worry about it. FWIW, I have a. collection of a couple of million of user agent strings. Most are very boring, some contain malware (yes, really!), some contain unique identifiers and other data they shouldn't - but you can always check your own.

Comment: you can always put code with different user agent. Or you can load real value from config file and use `.gitignore` to not send this config on GitHub. It is common method to keep passwords, tokens, API keys, etc. You keep them in separated file which is not send on GitHub. And you send config with some fake data and description how user has to set own values.